# Accessing a webpage that requires basic HTTP Auth

Tags: python

I am trying to webscrape a website that asks for credentials as a pop-up.

This is the kind of pop-up you get when a website wants HTTP Auth.

```
import requests 
r = requests.get('https://thewebsiteiwant.com', auth=('Myuser', 'Mypass'))
print(r.status_code) #This is now 401, however it used to be 200
```

Things I have tried:

1. Using `requests.Session()`, and posting to the login page first. There is technically a login page, however that page is not shown at all when attempting to access the page directly.
2. Looking at saved cookies from Chrome and attempting to recreate them in Python.
3. Copying the network request as a cURL and then using a cURL to Python translator.
4. Using cookielib to store cookies.
5. Adding user agents to requests.

Selenium will not work with this project. This program will be running on a headless RPi.

Comment: Does your auth work if you manually log in ?

Comment: Yes, it works as expected

Comment: Try specifying the domain for your auth, so it's clear that you want to login there:  `from requests_ntlm import HttpNtlmAuth` and `auth=HttpNtlmAuth('DOMAIN HERE\\user','pass')`

Comment: Oh I should mention you could find `request_ntlm` here https://github.com/requests/requests-ntlm

Comment: Oh. My. God. MooingRawr, it seems to be working. You have no idea how much potential work you just saved me from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If auth is working normally (manual enter) maybe you can try sepeciying the dormain for your auth, so the program knows where exactly you are trying to log into. This can be achieve by using the module `request_ntlm` found [here.](https://github.com/requests/requests-ntlm)

You use it by:

```
from requests_ntlm import HttpNtlmAuth
```

and where you put your `auth` in the `request.get()` :

```
auth=HttpNtlmAuth('DOMAIN HERE\\user','pass')
```